# Erlang SNS amazon erlcloud fails with socket_error nxdomain, Amazon Moved Permanently

Tags: amazon-web-services, erlang

Each time I am trying  to use erlcloud_sns (amazon SNS) I got error

```
erlcloud_sns:list_topics_all().
erlcloud_sns:create_topic("Topic2fromerlConsole").
erlcloud_sns:publish_to_topic("arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:AuTopic" , "my message", "subj").
```

I got one error

```
** exception error: {sns_error,{socket_error,{nxdomain,[{lhttpc_client,send_request,                                                                      1,                                                                       [{file,"src/lhttpc_client.erl"},{line,222}]},                                                        {lhttpc_client,execute,9,                                                                       [{file,"src/lhttpc_client.erl"},{line,171}]},                                                        {lhttpc_client,request,9,                                                                       [{file,"src/lhttpc_client.erl"},{line,93}]}]}}}
     in function  erlcloud_sns:sns_xml_request/3 (src/erlcloud_sns.erl, line 574)
     in call from erlcloud_sns:create_topic/2 (src/erlcloud_sns.erl, line 153)
```

ssl was started, sns was configured successfully

Updated:

After [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35145409/3091372) with my domain, I got error "Moved Permanently"

```
erlcloud_sns:publish_to_topic("arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:AuTopic" , "my message", "subj")..


Error: [lhttpc_client,211,"eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com",80,
        [binary,{packet,http},{active,false}],
        infinity,false]
** exception error: {sns_error,{http_error,301,"Moved Permanently",
                                           <<"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>301 Moved Permanently"...>>}}
     in function  erlcloud_sns:sns_xml_request/3 (src/erlcloud_sns.erl, line 574)
     in call from erlcloud_sns:list_topics/2 (src/erlcloud_sns.erl, line 299)
     in call from erlcloud_sns:list_all/5 (src/erlcloud_sns.erl, line 594)
```

How to make erlcloud sns works? Any suggestion would be helpful

error 301 for s3 is in url name, but nothing for sns in  [error codes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-api-error.html)

**Update-2**

**Fixed:**
I specified uncorrect host("sns.eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com") instead of "sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"(correct)

Comment: 'nxdomain' means non existent domain, check the hostname it's connecting to is correct and that whatever domain name resolution service you have available can resolve it.

Comment: Also checking [this thread](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2010-March/050349.html) which is about possible causes of `nxdomain` error could be helpful.

Comment: my resolv.conf
cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 127.0.1.1

 lhttpc_sock:connect("sns.amazonaws.com",80, [binary,{packet,http},{active,false}], infinity,false).
{error,nxdomain}


 ping "sns.amazonaws.com"
ping: unknown host sns.amazonaws.com

Comment: Yep, so looks like your nameserver can't resolve it, nothing to do with Erlang or AWS; your machine OS config or environment, or something else is broken. Now, I can't know that `127.0.1.1` is incorrect, but it's VERY unusual. `127.0.0.1` would be much more likely 99.999999% of the time...

Comment: add 
echo "nameserver 192.168.0.1" >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf, but still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into a similar issue, and after a little bit of digging I saw it is using a default host of sns.amazonaws.com, which is not resolvable. Overriding with a region-specific hostname, such as 'sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com' (or eu-west-1 based on your publish example) solves it. When doing your configure, just be sure to use configure/3 to provide your hostname. I'm using erlcloud from Elixir, so my simple example is:

```
sns_host = "sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" |> String.to_char_list
:erlcloud_sns.configure(access_key_id, secret_access_key, sns_host)
```

... which finally allowed my list_topics to return valid info, rather than an nxdomain error. Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help. If it took care of the problem for you, I'd definitely appreciate having this answer marked as accepted.

Comment: not exactly "accepted", I added " Amazon Moved Permanently" to name of post, now I got another error, response "exception error: {sns_error,{http_error,301,"Moved Permanently",
                                           <<"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>301 Moved Permanently" and sns still does not works

Comment: What hostname did you try that with?

Comment: "sns.eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com" my fault, I should use this "sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"

Comment: Yep, beat me to it. :) Glad its all working for you now.